# Android Material TextInputLayout error message is displayed behinde Material TextInputEditText child

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-constraintlayout, android-textinputlayout

Iam currently creating a Android UI with Material components. 
In my activity i use the error feature of the com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout-component.

The problem is that if to many components show an error the error messages is not displayed correctly. It looks like the message is behind the material.textfield.TextInputEditText, which is the child of the TextInputLayout. Please look at the screenshot for clarification.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVSxv.jpg)

Any guesses?

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.createOffer.CreateOfferActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/offerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/postOffer_Image"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Description"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/createOffer"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/component_label_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/postOffer_createOfferButton_Text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_PurchaseDate" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_Price"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/postOffer_editTextPrice_hint"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Category"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_Description">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_Category"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="@string/postOffer_Category"
            android:inputType=""
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Price"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_ExpireDate">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown_ctagory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_ExpireDate"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/postOffer_ExpireDateHint"
            android:inputType="none"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_PurchaseDate"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_Category">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_expireDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_PurchaseDate"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:hint="@string/postOffer_PurchaseDateHint"
            android:inputType="none"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/createOffer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_ExpireDate">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_purchaseDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_Description"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/general_description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="5"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="255"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Price"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/offerImage">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/description_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:importantForAutofill="no" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Regards :)

Comment: Why don't you just add some margin/padding?

Comment: I already tried working with margin and padding. But this wont fix the issue. Any other Ideas?

Comment: Try a vertical linear layout. Or maybe the layout gets shrunk down if the entire screen is full. Try wrapping it in a ScrollView as well. If neither helps, post the whole xml.

Comment: The vertical linear layout did not fix the issue. I put the whole xml into the original questions since it was too long for the answer field.

Comment: Did my new answer work?

Comment: Hi, had no time this weekend. I'll test your answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you accidentally connected the wrong dots of the constraint layout.
Compare these lines:

```
android:id="@+id/layout_Category"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_ExpireDate"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_Price">
<!--            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Price"-->
<!--            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_ExpireDate"-->
```

It works on my PC. But ofc i don't have your strings and image.
I added some more margin too.

[[Screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoD8v.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoD8v.png)

Full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/offerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Description"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/createOffer"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="string/postOffer_createOfferButton_Text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_PurchaseDate" />
        <!--            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/component_label_horizontal_margin"-->

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_Description"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:hint="string/general_description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="5"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="255"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Price"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/offerImage">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/description_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:importantForAutofill="no" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_Price"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:hint="string/postOffer_editTextPrice_hint"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Category"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_Description">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_Category"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="string/postOffer_Category"
            android:inputType=""
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_ExpireDate"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_Price">
            <!--            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_Price"-->
            <!--            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
            <!--            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
            <!--            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_ExpireDate"-->
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown_ctagory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_ExpireDate"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:hint="string/postOffer_ExpireDateHint"
            android:inputType="none"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_PurchaseDate"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_Category">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_expireDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_PurchaseDate"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:hint="string/postOffer_PurchaseDateHint"
            android:inputType="none"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/createOffer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_ExpireDate">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_purchaseDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried it using your code. But still the same error occurred. I actually shortened the length of the text but no changes. Might it be helpful if i provide you the strings and my theme?

Answer (score 0):

Set error to your TextInputEditText instead of TextInputLayout,

```
 description_EditText.setError("Error Message");
```

Comment: This would just be a workaround since this changes the behaviour of the error message. I will provide a screenshot later but unfortunately this is no solution :/

Comment: This is the only way out, as per the style you have applied. Either you can go for Toast or Snackbar to display an error message.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help. A Toast or Snackbar is sadly not possible in my situation as you can see on the screenshot.